# using "for" command in hp unix

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ksh, hp-ux

The below for doesn't work in hp-ux. However, it works on redhat machine. could please let me know what is incorrect here?

```
#/bin/ksh
Rowcount=`wc -l $acList | awk -F " " '{print $1}'`

for ((i=1; i<=Rowcount; i++)); do
.
.
.
```

Error i'm getting is:

```
 syntax error at line 4 : `(' unexpected
```

Comment: @fedorqui still the same error  `(' unexpected

Comment: I see it is fine either `i<=Rowcount` or `i<=$Rowcount`. What I see is that you could directly do `Rowcount=$(wc -l < $acList)`. Using `< file` avoids the extra space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a while loop:

```
i=1
while (( i <= Rowcount ))
do
   # Your code
   (( i+= 1 ))
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this syntax :

```
#!/bin/ksh
for f in $(wc -l $acList | awk -F " " '{print $1}')
do
        print "blabla : $f"
done
```

Comment: in my case Rowcount value is 3, i have tried your command but it only prints once. i want a set of operations to be done for 'Rowcount' no of times (here 3).

Comment: @user215827 I see (but don't understand) and I can't test it now, sorry